# Network Performance / SMB-CIFS / Guidance

Tags: networking, performance, ubuntu-12.04, truenas, iperf

I'm an IT professional working out of my home office.  I'm having some performance problems (NAS file copies) which I'm trying to isolate, using iperf. My question is on iperf.

Infrastructure - Gigabit switches (Netgear), not crossing switches. All adapters GigE.

 Server 1 - Ubuntu 12.04, running Samba 

 Server 2 - NAS4Free - running on VMware ESXi 5.5

My original problem - Large file transfers (1GB), particularly receive (client requests a file from server) is very slow, 10X slower on the NAS4Free box than the Samba Server.  In general I'm testing using a Windows client but I'm getting similar results from a Linux client (also Ubuntu).  This is provided for informational purposes.  I think the iperf results highlight the problem and that is where my question lies.

I ran iPerf, using the defaults (TCP).  Both servers are about the same showing 690MBytes and 683MBytes transfer speeds.  That's decent throughput and doesn't seem to be the problem.

I ran iPerf set up for UDP (both server and client). I stepped up the bandwidth by 100's - up to 800m (iperf -c ip-addr -u -b 800m).  These results clearly show a problem on the NAS4Free unit (running under VMware)

On Ubuntu/Samba - I can see when I hit the bandwidth limits.  Jitter and discards remain low, with the worst case at 700m where jitter was .053 and I lost 193 frames out of 527954 for a .037% loss.

I have two more virtual machines on the ESXi host, running Ubuntu 12.04.  They're running the same drivers on the virtual NICs as the NAS4Free box. Like the Ubuntu/Samba standalone unit there was no excessive packet loss even when the transfer is saturating the line.

On NAS4Free - It's a different story and I start getting packet loss between 300m and 400m and it just gets worse. This seems to be the problem.

```
Performance Table
            Bandwidth        Jitter           Lost/Total Datagrams
  -b 100m = 101Mbits/sec     0.030 ms         0   / 85471 (0%)
  -b 200m = 202Mbits/sec     0.026 ms         196 /172284 (0.11%)
  -b 300m = 301Mbits/sec     0.031 ms         514 /256312 (0.2%)
  -b 400m = 390Mbits/sec     0.037 ms        11861/343757 (3.5%) 
  -b 500m = 391Mbits/sec     0.053 ms        45983/378627 (12%) 
  -b 600m = 393Mbits/sec     0.061 ms       146109/480261 (31%)
```

Any thoughts on what's causing this?  What should I be looking at?  What tests should I run?

Thanks in advance for any help.  Apologies up front.  I don't often post (anywhere) so I hope I provided the proper amount of information in a reasonable format.